# check .txt file content if it match the text in the text box c#

Tags: c#, validation, encryption

Hi i need to validate a text-box input throw a .dat file[plain text] if it matches it do other stuff and if not i displays a pop up message
any help would be appreciated
and if you can also tell me how to encrypt that .dat file to more secure

***Thank you***

Comment: It would help if you would be a littlebit more descriptive? Is this a webpage using ASP.NET or Winforms? Also posting code samples would be useful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
// read file content into a string
String fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"c:\file.dat");

// compare TextBox content with file content
if (fileContent.Equals(myTextBox.Text))
{
    // do something
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error!");
}
```

Comment: I have combined your code with stream reader [thanks m.edmondson] and it worked. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx), that will allow you to read the file into your app.